# StreamReader ReadLineAsync ignores carriage return and hangs

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have simple `TcpListener` which accepts a pending connection and I read data from `NetworkStream` with using a `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`.

`TcpClient` writes data to the stream.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed
> ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately
> followed by a line feed ("\r\n")

The problem is that `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync` ignores the carriage return and never reads the line.

Server:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var listener = TcpListener.Create(22);
    listener.Start();
    var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(networkStream, leaveOpen: true);
            sw = new StreamWriter(networkStream, leaveOpen: true);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var clientData = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            sr?.Close();
            sw?.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Server ReadLineAsync hangs for CR
    var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 13 };
    
    // Server ReadLineAsync works for LF
    // var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10 };

    var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 22);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

This client is only for testing purposes. The real client will be an external application which will send data ended by CR.

Comment: Why do you think streamreader searches for a CR? for windows it is CR,LF and for linux it is LF. So it probably looks for the LF

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Because the text he quotes is literally stated as such [in the microsoft docs for StreamReader.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline). It doesn't state any difference per platform.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);` for new line

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Accroding to MS docs it should looks also for CR not only for LF.

Comment: @viveknuna if it is platform-depended, your proposed solution would fail if the client is run on windows and the server on Linux, or reversed...

Comment: That is non-closed network stream so "or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n")" probably means it had to wait for next character to see if it is \n or anything else. Should work perfectly fine when you write anything else into that stream on the client. May mean writing your own method that instead returns string as soon as it sees \r but ignores next \n on subsequent call (awkward but will work for you) (that probably should be posted as answer... but I'm too lazy to confirm)

Comment: [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L758) literally states `if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')`...

Comment: @JHBonarius and [line 768](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L768) indeed shows that it will wait for that extra character to check for `\n` - good find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StreamReader behaves exactly as described in documentation. Unfortunately it does it by *waiting* for next character following `\r` to see if it is `\n` or not.

Code for both sync and async version ([reference code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L737) ) is roughly

```
 if (currentChar == `\r`) {
      nextChar = ReadNextCharFromBufferOrStream();
      if (nextChar == `\n`) {
        //ignore
      } else {
         UnRead(nextChar);
      }
      return resultUpToR;
 }
```

In your case stream is not closed yet but at the moment of the call the last character is `\r` - and as result reader sits and waits for next character - it will give you the string when stream is either closed or gets any other subsequent character.

If you want behavior where `\r` instantly terminates the string and return you need to write your own version of the "read line" that will return string as soon as it sees `\r` and skip `\n` if *previous* character was `\r`. Or switch to always sending `\n` which does not have this problem.